# Next.js JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side

Currently, my backend gives me access and a refresh token to authorize users. In a previous project, I've just saved tokens into local storage and authorized users client-side.

My current project is locked for public users, I am showing an alert with information that the app is only for registered users only.

Is there any way to authorize users SSR and get rid of tokens from local storage?

Comment: What is your setup? Are you using Nodejs with JWT for the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your setup is, but couldn't you just use cookies instead? They can be accessed server side.